# Align text in center in css in mobile using media screen

Tags: css

i am trying to center align the text on mobile but it's not working.
[image]
here is the code

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 100px) {
  .info1{
    
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
   
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="info1">
      <p style=" display:inline-block; "> Contact : +97252387
 ,  </p>             
   <p style=" display:inline-block; ">Dizengoff square 85 Tel Aviv</p>
  </div>
```

text-align is also no working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your centering is not working because your media query is

```
@media screen and (max-width: 100px) {...
```

so it is probably working under 100px. But I am guessing you meant 1000px?

**EDIT**: here are 2 working examples:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .info1{
    
    width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
   
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="info1">
      <p style=" display:inline-block; "> Contact : +97252387
 ,  </p>             
   <p style=" display:inline-block; ">Dizengoff square 85 Tel Aviv</p>
  </div>
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .info1 {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
   
  }
  .info1 > p {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="info1">
      <p style=" display:inline-block; "> Contact : +97252387
 ,  </p>             
   <p style=" display:inline-block; ">Dizengoff square 85 Tel Aviv</p>
  </div>
```

for the last example please note you can remove

```
.info1 > p {
    width: 100px;
}
```

if you don't want fixed width.

Comment: oops that was by mistake. But its still not working when i change it to 1000px or 500px.it just went to right and out of screen